# Find duplicates in a list without a nested loop?

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm currently working on an assignment where I have to optimise some code. One of the slowest methods is a method to find duplicate elements in a list.

Duplicates in the scenario work like this:
say you have a list of elements, each with two ID's, x and y. each x value can only be paired with one y value, else it counts it as a duplicate and both the original and the duplicate must be added to a list.

For example, the list of elements is (1,2) (1,2) (1,3)
In this instance, the list of duplicates would contain 4 elements, (1,2)(1,3) and (1,2)( 1,3), as they both have the same x value, but a different y value. 
(1,2)(1,2) wouldn't be classed as a duplicate as the x and y values are the same.

The current code uses a nested for loop, which checks if the x values of the two elements are equal but the y values are different, but this is quite slow.

In the actual scenario, the elements are kidney donors being matches to patients. So each donor can only donate to a single patient. X and Y are strings representing the ID of the patient and the donor.

If anyone knows a quicker way of doing this, it would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Use. A. `Map`. Chuck the whole lot into a `Map<Integer, List<Pair>>` - all the work will be done for you.

Comment: Show the code as reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Long>> mmap = linkTable.stream()
      .collect(groupingBy(DonorsToPatientPair::getDonorID,
            groupingBy(DonorsToPatientPair::getPatientID, counting())));
```

Variable mmap now contains a map of keys to a map of values for this key to the frequency. If you want to get the number of occurences of (d, p), you can get it like this:

```
long freq = mmap.get(d).get(p)
```

For processing the map, you can use code like this:

```
for (int donor : mmap.keySet()) {
  Map<Integer, Long> patientMap = mmap.get(donor);
  if (patientMap.size() < 2) {
    continue; // no duplicates
  }
  // *** your code here ***
}
```

For your own code, you have in a loop the donor and a map from patients to their frequency. The remaining work should be easy to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks, managed to get this working. Ends up being about 95% faster than the original code. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the array of pairs with the x values as sort criteria.
Then slice the array in smaller arrays of pairs with same x values.
Then you look for duplicates only locally in the smaller chunks, using your current algorithm. Although this still has nested loops, it will execute faster, because the search is limited to small arrays and the search with two nested loops has complexity O(n*n) when n is the number of elements.

Answer (score 0):

I am just giving you a hint
Treat it as a graph problem and draw an edge between (u,v) and later if you find a n edge directed to v that's duplicate

Answer (score -1):

You can use a set of List of integer:

```
Set<List<Integer>> uniqueIds = new HashSet(listOfIds)
```

The job is done by the hashset constructor.

Comment: So how exactly would I implement that? I need to return a list of objects and the IDs are actually stored as strings. So far i have this:  
                                                             
    `Set<Pair<String, String>> uniqueIds = new HashSet();
       
       for(DonorsToPatientPair donor : linkTable)
       { 
            if(!uniqueIds.add(new Pair<>(donor.getDonorID(),donor.getPaientID())))
            {              
                results.add(donor);
            }
       }`

Comment: Rawtypes are bad - never use rawtypes. Also - this doesn't solve the problem.